# Problem with wordpress pagination

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, pagination

First of all thank you everyone for all the knowledge base i got reading trough stackexchange. For the first time i couldn't find an answer to my problem.

The matter is that with this custom query (which has the purpose to search trough the posts with multiple taxonomy fields):

```
global $wp_query;
$tax_query = array();
$parametri = array(
                        'ih_tipo_struttura' =>  array('tipo_struttura','IN'),
                        'ih_localita'       =>  array('localita', 'IN'),
                        'ih_stelle'         =>  array('stelle', 'IN'),
                        'ih_categorie'      =>  array('categorie', 'AND'),
                        'ih_servizi'        =>  array('servizi', 'AND')
                    );
// Faccio il post dei parametri e li inserisco nella query
foreach ($parametri as $post => $taxonomy) {
    if ( isset($_GET[$post]) && !empty($_GET[$post]) ){ 
        $tax_query[] = array(
                    'taxonomy'  => $taxonomy[0],
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'terms'     => $_GET[$post],
                    'operator'  => $taxonomy[1]
                    ); 
    }
}
// Parametri base della query
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => $tax_query
);
// Parametri paginazione
if ( $pagination ) {
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args['posts_per_page'] = 2;
    $args['paged'] = $paged;
} else {
    $args[] = array( 'posts_per_page' => 20);   // Se imposto la paginazione a false ritorno i primo 20 risultati
}
// Eseguo la query
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
return $wp_query;
```

everything works fine until i try to do some pagination.

When i pass trough the url some $_GET parameters like:

```
http://mywebsite/ricerca/?ih_localita%5B%5D=riccione&ih_localita%5B%5D=rimini&ricerca_hotel=true
```

or

```
http://mywebsite/ricerca/page/2/?ih_localita=riccione&ih_localita%5B%5D=rimini&ricerca_hotel=true
```

there's no problem but if try:

```
http://mywebsite/ricerca/page/2/?ih_localita%5B0%5D=riccione&ih_localita%5B1%5D=rimini&ricerca_hotel=true
```

wordpress cut off all the search parameters returning the url just like:

```
http://mywebsite/ricerca/page/2/?ricerca_hotel=true
```

I'm getting crazy with this so i would really appreciate any help.

Thx

Comment: And just FYI: [this question about custom loop pagination has been asked *many, many times* before here at WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=custom+loop+pagination).

Answer (score 2):

Don't stomp on the `$wp_query` global. Use your own variable to hold your query instead:

```
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then, you can use a little trick to fix pagination. Do this *before* the loop:

```
global $wp_query;
// Store it for safekeeping
$temp_wp_query = $wp_query;
// Now blank it out
$wp_query = null;
// Now populate it with your custom query
$wp_query = $custom_query;
```

Then, *after* the loop closes, restore the original query object:

```
$wp_query = $temp_wp_query;
```

Now, your pagination *should* work properly.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply but with your solution i'm still having the problem. The matter is not really about the query itself (that is actually working) but more about passing array trough the url ( ih_localita%5B0%5D=riccione ) on paginated url. Any others idea !?

Comment: What are those URL query variables, where do they come from, and what are you doing with them?

Comment: They are the result of a checkbox array <input '.$checked.' type="checkbox" name="ih_struttura[]" value="'.$term->slug.'">' . $term->name . '</input>

Comment: However... i'm thinking about serializing them with some javascript cause i cant find any other solution... something like: mywebsite/ricerca/?ih_localita=term1,term2,term3 actually works using an explode(',', $_GET[$post]);

Comment: Might [**`add_query_arg()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) and [**`get_query_var()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) be helpful here?

Comment: Don't know about it Bennet... Actually i didn't give it a try but it seems illogical...

Comment: Ok, just to five it a final chance i tried using query vars but still... not working! :(

Answer (score 0):

At a second glance i figure out that the problem is probably with url rewrite on pagination which doesn't work well with this url format:

```
page/2/?ih_localita%5B0%5D=riccione&ih_localita%5B1%5D=rimini
```

cutting off all the multiple checkbox parameter and rewriting it as:

```
page/2/
```

Now my solution will probably be to use another format to pass checkbox multiple value so i will do something like

```
page/2/?ih_localita=rimini,riccione
```

that actually works fine but it would be nice to figure out where the problem is...